# How to get sum of column in datatable

Tags: c#

I want to calculate Total of weight and volume column separably in
   data table.

For E.g

```
Route   Weight   Volume
R1       10       100
R1       20       200 
R2       10       50
```

I want result as

```
Route   Weight   Volume
R1       30       300
R2       10       50
```

i have used below code,

```
   var query = from row in DTRationData.AsEnumerable()
                        group row by row.Field<string>("RouteCode") into grp
                        orderby grp.Key
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = grp.Key,
                            Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Weight"))                           
                        };

            foreach (var grp in query)
            {
                DRow = DTRouteData.NewRow();
                DRow["RouteCode"] = grp.Id;
                DRow["Weight"] = grp.Sum/1000;                
                DTRouteData.Rows.Add(DRow);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another property in your anonymous type:

```
.......
select new
{
    Id = grp.Key,
    WeightSum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Weight")),
    VolumeSum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Volume"))                              
};
```